# django_pandas.io read_frame() giving too many SQL variable error

Tags: django

I stumbled upon this weird problem, the "TOO MANY SQL VARIABLES" in sqlite3 django error is coming not while fetching the objects via the line

```
objects = Model_Name.objects.filter(CN = some_name)
```

but the error is coming when I convert this to df using django_pandas.io.read_frame()

```
df = read_frame(objects)
```

The queryset here has around 80 variables and nearly ~7000 rows.

So I decided to convert the queryset to data frame in a loop with the code

```
df = []
for items in range(0, len(objects), 100):
    df.append(read_frame(objects[items:items+100]))
df.append(read_frame(objects[-1*len(objects)%100:]))
```

but this is giving me another error at `df.append(read_frame(objects[items:items+100]))`
saying `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_iterable_class'`

Note:- The code for only one-time indexing like `read_frame(objects[100:168])` runs fine but the same line gives that Attribute error when running in a loop.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`read_frame` takes a queryset as a parameter. The problem is that `len(objects)` evaluates the `objects` queryset, and slicing a queryset that has been evaluated returns a list, not a queryset.

Taken from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

> Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list.

If you use queryset.count() instead, then the queryset will not be evaluated. The following code worked for me:

```
dfs = []
qs_length = queryset.count()
step = 100
for i in range(0, qs_length - (qs_length % step), step):
    dfs.append(read_frame(queryset[i : i + step]))
dfs.append(read_frame(queryset[qs_length - (qs_length % step) : qs_length]))
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```